# Compute factorized and marginalized distribution of the graph

Tags: probability

I am trying to compute the factorized joint distribution of the graph below. I was wondering if this is correct.

$p(y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2,z_3) = p(z_1)p(z_2)p(z_3)p(y_1|z_1,z_2,z_3)p(y_2|z_3)$

The question now asks me to compute the marginal $p(z_1|y_1,y_2)$ from the factorized joint distribution and the answer is

$p(z_1|y_1,y_2) = p(z_1)\sum_{z_2}p(z_2)\sum_{z_3}p(y_1|z_1,z_2,z_3)p(y_2|z_3)p(z_3)$

1. It looks kinda weird to me and I was wondering if there is another expression that I can arrive at ?
2. How different would my answer be if I am told to compute the marginal $p(z_1,y_1,y_2)$ ? It looks like there won't be any change if all i have to do is sum over $z_2,z_3$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation
$$
\textstyle
p(z_1 \mid y_1, y_2) = p(z_1) \sum_{z_2} p(z_2) \sum_{z_3} p(y_1 \mid z_1, z_2, z_3)p(y_2 \mid z_3)p(z_3) \tag{$1$}
$$
does not hold in general. Instead, it should be
$$
\textstyle
p(z_1 \mid y_1, y_2) \propto p(z_1, y_1, y_2) = p(z_1) \sum_{z_2} p(z_2) \sum_{z_3} p(y_1 \mid z_1, z_2, z_3)p(y_2 \mid z_3)p(z_3) \tag{$2$}
$$
where $\propto$ means "is proportional to". This is because
$$
\textstyle
p(z_1 \mid y_1, y_2) = {p(z_1, y_1, y_2)}/{p(y_1, y_2)}  \tag{$3$}
$$
and if we want to compare $p(z_1 = v_1 \mid y_1, y_2)$ and $p(z_1 = v_2 \mid y_1, y_2)$ for two values $v_1$, $v_2$ of $z_1$, we only need to compare the numerators since the denominators are the same for both.

Comment: thank you very much ! I have also confirmed it with the teaching assistant. They did leave out the denominator.